Find fixed point iterations $x=g(x)$ to find roots of $0=f(x) = e^x + x^2 - 4$
I am finding trouble looking for 2 possible $g(x)$s to use for the fixed point iteration of $$f(x) = e^x + x^2 - 4$$
So far, I have guessed that the solution lies in the interval $[-2, 1]$, and I have tried all the obvious possible $g(x)$s, but when I go to compare their if their $|g(x)'| < 1$, they do not end up being feasible. Can I get some help in this? Thank you!
Edit: I have also tried different intervals such as $[-1.96, -1.97]$, but have so far only gotten one $g(x)$ that satisfies this condition, but I would like to find at least two $g(x)$s that satisfy this function.

The interval $[1,-2]$ is empty because $1>-2$. Did you mean $[-2,1]$? The same happens with the interval $[-1.96,-1.97]$

Yes I did mean $[-2, 1]$, thank you for the correction!

You could add the Newton method for $e^{-x}f(x)=1+e^{-x}(x^2-4)$. Such variations usually give different Newton iterations.

You fixed the interval $[1,-2]$, but you didn't fix the interval $[-1.96, -1.97]$

We want to use Fixed-Point Iteration to find the roots of
$$f(x) = e^x + x^2 - 4$$
If we plot $f(x)$ there are two roots.

One approach for FPI is to use Newton's Method to pick a $g(x)$. This gives the fixed-point iteration $x_{n+1} = g(x_n)$ with
$$g(x) = x - \dfrac{f(x)}{f'(x)} = x-\dfrac{x^2+e^x-4}{2 x+e^x}$$
We can now find
$$g'(x) = \frac{\left(e^x+2\right) \left(x^2+e^x-4\right)}{\left(2 x+e^x\right)^2}$$
If we plot $|g'(x)|$ and the line $y = 1$, we have

This can provide ranges which can be used to analytically verify $|g'(x)| < 1$ over the two selected ranges.
We should find the two roots of $f(x)$, which are located at
$$x=-1.96464 \lor x=1.05801$$
I will let you fill in the details.
